# material js date-picker and ng-model date string mismatch

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, material-design

I have some questions about AngularJS ng-model and Angular Materia date-picker.
I have two problems. One is that the date shown on the date-picker's input is different than the ng-model value. The other one is that when a user picks the date on the calendar, ng-model value is different than the date that user picked. Here are the details.

So I have this string variable in a controller
`$scope.formData["begin_date"] = "2017-09-25"`

And This is my html tag

```
<md-input-container >
    <label>Start date</label>
        <md-datepicker required ng-model="formData.begin_date"></md-datepicker>
        </md-input-container>
```

But here is what my browser shows me. The date that I wanted to display is 2017-09-25 on the input but 2017-09-24 is displayed instead. Here is the image.
[date displayed on the date picker input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24lWC.png)

And I don't understand how I can fix this problem to show the exact date that I wanted to show.

Also, I want users to be able to pick a date using date-picker and see the date that is picked on the browser. However, when a user picks the date, the ng-model that is binded to the date-picker displays different date. For example, a user picks `2017-09-28` on the calendar like below.
[user picks 2017-09-28](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY8ri.png)

But the angular ng-model shows the different date value than the date that user picked from the calendar like below. On the web browsers it shows `"2017-09-29T00:00:00.000Z"` and I just want to simply display `2017-09-28`

How can I fix these two problems?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> So I have this string variable in a controller $scope.formData["begin_date"] = "2017-09-25"

Write `begin_date` as `Date` object:

```
$scope.formData = {
    begin_date: new Date("2017-09-25")
  };
```

<kbd>[DEMO CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/Fess-81/pen/PKBmNj)</kbd>